# Error while counting number of character,lines and words in java

Tags: java

i have written the following code to count the number of character excluding white spaces,count number of words,count number of lines.But my code is not showing proper output.

```
import java.io.*;

 class FileCount
{


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream("sample.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
    int i;
    int countw=0,countl=0,countc=0;
    do
    {
        i=br.read();
        if((char)i==(' '))
            countw++;
        else if((char)i==('\n'))
            countl++;
        else 
            countc++;



    }while(i!=-1);
    System.out.println("Number of words:"+countw);
    System.out.println("Number of lines:"+countl);
    System.out.println("Number of characters:"+countc);
}
}
```

my file sample.txt has

```
hi my name is john
hey whts up
```

and my out put is

```
Number of words:6
Number of lines:2
Number of characters:26
```

Comment: You also should provide sample input and sample output and describe what's wrong with the output.

Comment: First thing to see is that in the second println `countw` should probably be `countl`.

Comment: You need to work on your logic. Your character count will be incorrect as it doesn't count spaces as characters, and your end of line check will only work on systems that use `\n` (i.e. Linux), but on windows it's `\r\n` which will add one character to the count. Also, 2 spaces between words will off your count: `Foo__bar_` (replace `_` with space) will show up as 3 words.

Comment: your counts aren't supposed to be exclusive. The end of a line is also the end a word and every none whitespace characteir is character.

Comment: Does not fix your problem, but you can simply write `i==' '` instead of `(char)i==(' ')`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error using Buffered Reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055732/error-using-buffered-reader)

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own questions.

Comment: @Don Roby i am not getting proper output thats why i am posting it again

Comment: What encoding are you using? If you are using something like utf16 or utf8 with surrogates, the character count will not match the byte count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to discard other whitespace characters as well including repeats, if any. A `split` around `\\s+` gives you words separated by not only all whitespace characters but also any appearance of those characters in succession.

Having got a list of all words in the `line` it gets easier to update the count of words and characters using length methods of array and `String`.

Something like this will give you the result:

```
String line = null;
String[] words = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    countl++;
    words = line.split("\\s+");
    countw += words.length;
    for (String word : words) {
        countc += word.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting [`readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), and [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Reading lines, instead of characters, saves line break checks, thus making the code more intuitive and concise.

Answer (score 0):

A new line means also that the words ends. 
=> There is not always a ' ' after each word.

```
  do
  {
  i=br.read();
    if((char)i==(' '))
        countw++;
    else if((char)i==('\n')){
        countl++;
        countw++;  // new line means also end of word
    }
    else 
        countc++;
}while(i!=-1);
```

End of file should also increase the number of words (if no ' ' of '\n' was the last character.
Also handling of more than one space between words is still not handled correctly.

=> You should think about more changes in your approach to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

class FileCount {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("sample.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
        int i;
        int countw = 0, countl = 0, countc = 0;
        do {
            i = br.read();
            if ((char) i == (' ')) { // You should also check for other delimiters, such as tabs, etc.
                countw++;
            }
            if ((char) i == ('\n')) { // This is for linux Windows should be different
                countw++; // Newlines also delimit words
                countl++;
            }  // Removed else. Newlines and spaces are also characters
            if (i != -1) {
                countc++; // Don't count EOF as character
            }


        } while (i != -1);


        System.out.println("Number of words " + countw);
        System.out.println("Number of lines " + countl); // Print lines instead of words
        System.out.println("Number of characters " + countc);
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
Number of words 8
Number of lines 2
Number of characters 31
```

Validation

```
$ wc sample.txt 
2  8 31 sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FileCount {
    /**
     *
     * @param filename
     * @return three-dimensional int array. Index 0 is number of lines
     * index 1 is number of words, index 2 is number of characters
     * (excluding newlines) 
     */
    public static int[] getStats(String filename) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

        int[] stats = new int[3];
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            stats[0]++;
            stats[1] += line.split(" ").length;
            stats[2] += line.length();
        }

        return stats;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] stats = new int[3];
        try {
            stats = getStats("sample.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Number of words:" + stats[1]);
        System.out.println("Number of lines:" + stats[0]);
        System.out.println("Number of characters:" + stats[2]);
    }

}
```